# this sort two vectors passed to function as references

Tags: c++, sorting

I try to sort one vector using another one values,
this is the code:

```
template <typename T>
    void ordered_by_old_indices(std::vector<T> const& values, std::vector<size_t> &indices) {
        //std::vector<size_t> indices(values.size());
        //std::iota(begin(indices), end(indices), static_cast<size_t>(0));
        //auto x = indices.begin();
        //std::cout << *x << std::endl;
        //auto y = indices.end()-1;
        //std::cout << *y << std::endl;

        std::sort(
            indices.begin(), indices.end(),
            [&](size_t a, size_t b) { return values[a] < values[b]; }
        );
        //return indices;
    }
```

but it gives me error :

```
vector subscript out of range
```

what is the problem here,it is just wrapper of sort???

Update:
the problem is that sort gives the comparing function values of elements of vector to be sorted ,I want a way so that sort pass the position of element not its value. this means passing 01234567.... but work on the given vector indices

Comment: "vector subscript out of range" means exactly that. Usually people refer to it as out-of-bounds-access. Now you need to catch the exception in the debugger and check all the relevant values at the time of the exception. `values` seems to be smaller than required.

Comment: both indices and values are same size

Comment: In this case, I would insert a `assert(values.size() == indices.size());` before the call of `std::sort()`. If it results in an abort you know why it doesn't work. If it doesn't anything this is, at least, a valuable hint for the reader.

Comment: no abort occurs

Comment: Then you may add another one also: `assert([&]() { for (size_t i : indices) { if (i >= values.size()) return false; } return true; }());` (Sorry, it looks a bit ugly as one-liner.)

Comment: the second one makes abort???but what is the relation between them?!!

Comment: I need sort indices according to values ,so why a and b takes the value of indices not just their position??

Comment: @Scheff that first one would only see if the input vectors have an equal size (which IMHO is not required). It doesn't guarantee that the indices stored in `indices` are valid for `values`...

Comment: Vote close: The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I agree with @JHBonarius: My first `assert()` was a bit short-handed. The 2nd one checks whether all indices in `indices` address existing elements in `values`. If it fails there is at least one index in `indices` which may result into an out-of-bound access to `values` (if used in e.g. `values[indices[i]]` or namely in the custom predicate you used for `sort()`).

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work. still working on it

```
template <typename T>
    void ordered_by_old_indices(std::vector<T> const& values, std::vector<size_t> &indices) {
        std::vector<size_t> indices_1(indices.size());
        std::iota(begin(indices_1), end(indices_1), static_cast<size_t>(0));
        std::sort(
            begin(indices_1), end(indices_1),
            [&](size_t a, size_t b) { return values[a] < values[b]; }
        );
        assert(values.size() == indices_1.size());
        //assert([&]() { for (size_t i : indices_1) { if (i >= values.size()) return false; } return true; }());

        //std::sort(
        //  begin(indices), end(indices),
        //  [&](size_t a, size_t b) { return indices_1[a] < indices_1[b]; }
        //);
        //now I should use sorted indices_1 to pushback original indices into indices
        for (std::vector<size_t>::iterator indices_1_it = indices_1.begin(); indices_1_it != indices_1.end(); indices_1_it ++)
        {
            indices.push_back(values[indices_1[]]);
        }
        //return indices;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function works, see below, (as I think you want it to) so what @Scheff said is that your indices are out of range of the values. So try to print your indices in your function to see if any of the indices[x] would cause values[indices[x]] to go out of bounds.

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
template <typename T>
void ordered_by_old_indices(std::vector<T> const& values, std::vector<size_t> &indices) {
    std::sort(
        indices.begin(), indices.end(),
        [&](size_t a, size_t b) { return values[a] < values[b]; }
    );
    //return indices;
}

void TestIndices() {
  std::vector<size_t> values(50);
  std::iota(begin(values), end(values), static_cast<size_t>(0));
  std::random_shuffle(values.begin(), values.end());
  std::vector<size_t> indices(values.size());
  std::iota(begin(indices), end(indices), static_cast<size_t>(0));
  auto x = indices.begin();
  std::cout << *x << std::endl;
  auto y = indices.end()-1;
  std::cout << *y << std::endl;
  ordered_by_old_indices(values, indices);
  std::cout << values.size() << indices.size() << "\n";
  for(int i = 0; i < values.size(); ++i) // print the values ordered by indices
    std::cout << indices[i] << " : " << values[indices[i]] << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Showing that his solution works for a specific input doesn't solve the problem. It only indicates that the question is not good, i.e. no debugging details.

Comment: the problem is that sort gives the comparing function values of elements of vector to be sorted,I want a way so that sort pass the position of element not its value.this means pas 01234567.... but work on the given vector indices

Comment: @ahmedallam I think you need to give an example input and output of at least 5 values to clarify the question.